# C# Read .html or .rtf and use it as Mail.Body

Tags: c#, email, outlook

```
        string Mailto = "username@domainname";
        string MailCc = "username@domainname";
        string Subject = "Test";
        ReadSignature();

        Outlook.Application app = new Outlook.Application();
        Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)app.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        mail.To = Mailto;
        mail.CC = MailCc;

        mail.Subject = Subject;

        mail.HTMLBody = "<html><body>This just a test</body></html>" + signature;
        mail.BodyFormat = Outlook.OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;

        mail.Display(true);
```

I want to open a mail on buttonclick as shown above. Works perfectly.
No I'm trying to figure out how I could read out a file and use it as body.

Background: I want to have like 4 different Mails which are all formatted nicely. So I thought I could write these files as .rtf, .doc, .msg or whatsoever and just copy these files into mail.htmlbody.

Comment: read the html-file and assign it to `mail.HTMLBody`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok right. Was pretty easy actually ;-)

```
        //Local File
        String htmlCode = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Test.html", Encoding.Default);

        //Webfile
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        String htmlCode = client.DownloadString(@"http://www.google.com");

        mail.HTMLBody = htmlCode + signature;
```

Comment: "htmlCode + signature" will not produced a valid HTML string. You cannot just concatenate two HTML documents, you must merge them.